# IE VBScript HTC Behavior - Static Variables between all Instances of Behavior?

Tags: vbscript, behavior, html-components

I'm not 100% sure what question I should ask - as I'm too sure on the best way to do this .. so let me describe what I'm trying to do (using a simplified example) and we'll go from there.

You have arbitrary HTML Elements (IMG, A, TD, whatever).
Via the CSS they are assigned an HTML Behavior

```
.BoldSelection { 
    behavior: url(SelectBold.htc); 
    border: thin solid black;  
}
```

The Behavior simply puts a thick border around the elements when they are clicked - BUT - they have to set the previously selected element with a normal border.

So here is the HTC source.  This would work if CurrentlyFocusedElementID was static between all instances of the behavior.  But it isn't.

```
<Public:Attach Event="onContentReady" onEvent="LoadInit" />

    <Script Language="VBScript" type="Text/VBScript">

        Sub LoadInit
            element.onClick = getRef("setFocusedElement")
        End Sub

        Sub setFocusedElement
            set ele = document.getElementByID(CurrentlyFocusedElementID)
            ele.style.border = "thin solid black"
            CurrentlyFocusedElementID = element.id
            element.style.border = "thick solid black"
        End Sub

    </Script>
```

I also thought that if I could store an arbitrary property or attribute within the containing document's DOM then I could use that as a common place to look for the last active element ...  alas I can't figure out a way to do that without using some sort of hack (ie. hijacking the body's class value)

I would like to keep the code all contained within the HTC.  I like the modular fashion of doing it this way .. that way I can simply assign the CSS Behavior and its done - no callbacks .. no parent attributes .. no HTML Components to declare.

How would you suggest I go about doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Code like this, deliberately designed to work only in IE, is the reason why we haven't been able to kill off IE6 in the corporate world yet, despite the fact that it's older than iPods. It is entirely possible to write apps for IE that don't lock out good browsers, too. Shame on you!

Comment: Well Joel - I do agree with you wholeheartedly.  But like everything - there is a place for it.

I'm using this for developing an HTML Application.  The corporate standard is IE - there are no other browsers.  This will never be hosted on a web server.   There is no point to write it for anything EXCEPT IE.

Comment: Yes, but you could write code for IE that wasn't in VBScript, and didn't depend on behaviors. Then you're adhering to the corporate standard, without taking away your company's ability to change their mind. When MS first invented HTC behaviors, they submitted them to the W3C. What if IE9 drops behavior support because the W3C rejected them? Sticking to standards, even in an IE-only shop, will save your company money in the long run.

Comment: Say, for example, your CEO finds out that Google Chrome is fifteen times faster than IE7 and decides to change the corporate standard to Chrome. Or maybe she gets fed up with the weekly security exploits in IE, and decides on a more secure browser. Except, she can't make that choice, because you've locked her in to IE, and doomed yourself to a crappy slow browser forever.

Comment: For my specific needs, Behaviors work best.  The code is encapsulated in the HTC file separately.  Its use is modular and the code is readable and intuitive.  Interestingly - I have already written this project once with everything contained in a single file.   It was a nightmare to manage.   I'm doing a rewrite using HTML Components and HTML Behaviors.  So far everything is very modular, and its easy to manage.   I also would say I've noticed a speed increase using this approach - things seem more responsive.

Comment: As for my choice to use VBScript - I do a lot of work with VBA in Access - so I'm comfortable with VBScript and can easily move my modules between VBScript HTAs and Access.

Comment: As I've already said - I agree on your sentiment about keeping things standard.  Myself, I use Macs at home.  I use Safari exclusively and love the fact that its 100% standards compliant.   Having said that - we live in a Microsoft world whether we like it or not.  I seriously doubt that W3C will reject HTML Behaviors - and I find it a near-impossibility for Microsoft to not keep future browsers backward compatible.   Behaviors have become far too popular for either Microsoft or the W3C to ignore.

Comment: In regards to companies being locked into certain products .. when a company gets to be a certain size - unless it's business is IT - it _has_ to standardize its software, hardware, and procedures.  It simply costs too much to support users in a diverse environment.  A large company cannot function properly without doing so.

Comment: Here's Microsoft's submission of HTC behaviors to the W3C, in 1998. If the W3C was going to accept this, don't you think it would have happened sometime in the last 11 years? At the time, IE was by far technically the best browser around. If it didn't happen then, what makes you think it would happen now that IE has fallen so far behind in performance and capability?
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents

Comment: I only keep harping on this because I based a large app on HTC behaviors (and their Mozilla cousin, XBL bindings - also not accepted by the W3C) in 1999, and it was an astonishing amount of work to rewrite all the client-side code into object-oriented javascript without behaviors later. It was worth it, the app is now faster, easier to maintain, and doesn't lock out non-IE browsers for no good reason. I just wish I had done it that way to begin with, so I'm just trying to save you (or your replacement) pain down the road.

Comment: I know this is a late comment but I wanted to add my .02.  HTA (HTML applications) are basically Internet Explorer windows hosted in an exe file.  Arguing and advising against using IE proprietary features is pointless in this instance as HTAs will always be running IE and HTCs can be *very* useful for achieving functionality not easily/usually available through normal scripting methods.

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece of the puzzle was .. expandos.  Custom arbitrary attributes.  Here is the completed .HTC

```
<Public:Attach Event="onContentReady" onEvent="LoadInit" />

  <Script Language="VBScript" type="Text/VBScript">

    ' This is an example HTC only.   If we were only setting borders, it'd make more sense to store
    ' the previous element's border type and keep the rest of the formatting.  For simplicity we are
    ' swapping out the class name

    Sub LoadInit

      ' No ID defined for this element.  Highlight it for the developer
      If element.id = "" Then
        element.style.bordercolor = "rgb(200,50,10)"
        element.style.borderwidth = "thin"
        element.style.borderstyle = "dashed"
        Exit Sub
      End If

      ' Attach our Click Events
      element.onClick = getRef("BoldIt")
      element.onDblClick = getRef("BoldItMore")

    End Sub


    ' Changes the Class Name for the current element, and if a previously
    ' selected element exists, restore its original classname
    Sub changeClass(newCSSClass)
      ' Storing the Expando on the document.body element
      Set ele = window.document.body

      ' Retrieve our two custom attributes - the ID of the element, and what its original ClassName was.
      LastEle = ele.getAttribute("LastHighlightedEle")
      LastEleClass = ele.getAttribute("LastHighlightedEleClass")

      ' If there was in fact a previously selected element - restore the classname
      If not isnull(LastEle) then
        set oldEle = window.document.getElementByID(LastEle)
        oldEle.className = LastEleClass
        set oldEle =  Nothing
      End If

      ' Set our two custom attributes to this element and adjust this element's CSS ClassName
      LastEle = element.id
      LastEleClass = element.className
      ele.setAttribute "LastHighlightedEle",LastEle
      ele.setAttribute "LastHighlightedEleClass",LastEleClass
      element.className = newCSSClass
    End Sub

    ' Single Click Event - 'Thick' is a CSS Style for a 3px border
    Sub BoldIt
      changeClass("Thick")
    End Sub

    ' Double Click Event - 'Thicker' is a CSS Style for a 4px border
    Sub BoldItMore
      changeClass("Thicker")
    End Sub

  </Script>
```